# "This raining is falling hard" would it be wrong? or how does it feels for you

Tags: writing, poetry

I know it is commonly said "This rain is falling hard" but I am working in a poem and "This raining is falling hard" fits perfect with all the metrics and the entire story.

But since I'm not a native speaker, does it feels odd like that? Would it really bother you if you listen to it? Would it feel like a foreigner is saying it, or would just feel poetical?

How would you feel it? Would you say it if you were in a specific country?
Or simply get rid and just go with "this rain is falling hard"

Comment: No, it doesn't work. Possibly **these raindrops are falling hard**?

Comment: There are many ways to talk about the idea you want. *Heavy* is the most common neutral adjective to use, as in *heavy rain*. But there are lots of more interesting ways, such as *in sheets*. *Sheets of rain descend endlessly from the skies* is one flowery example of a poetic way to say this.

Answer (score 1):

Don't go with either, those are not something commonly said. "This rain is falling hard" sounds bad, but "This raining is falling hard" sounds worse. Both are improper English. People say "It is raining hard" or "The rain is coming down hard". Stray away from those sentences you provided, I have never heard anybody say those.

Comment: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=rain+is+falling+hard&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Crain%20is%20falling%20hard%3B%2Cc0

Comment: @RonaldSole I have lived in America all my life, and never once have heard anybody say that. Despite what people look up on google, it's not a phrase people use in daily life, its not something that people say when they go outside and see it is raining, like if its pouring rain - nobody says "This raining is falling hard".

Comment: I agree. I have lived in Africa and Europe all of my life and I've never heard it either - although **it's raining hard** is common enough. Evidently, though, others have.

Comment: I wonder where he lives to have heard that? He seems to think it is a common phrase.